# How to hide an element only if it matches specific hash?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to hide a form only if it's on the root site, or on the specific hash https://www.example.com/#uno. My code below is causing the form is not show on all the subpages (/#dos, /#tres, etc). Can someone help me understand what is happening?

```
$(function(){
    if (location.hash == "" || location.hash == "#uno"){
      $("#form").hide();
    } else {
      $("#form").show();
    };
}());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you hide the form once, but you don't make it reappear until you reload the page. (You only check the hash once, when loading the entire page, not when the hash changes.

```
function showHideForm() {
    if (location.hash == "" || location.hash == "#uno"){
        $("#form").hide();
    } else {
        $("#form").show();
    };
}

window.onhashchange = showHideForm;
```

Comment: Jelle Posthuma, when I navigate to other tabs, then back to the #uno table, the form is still showing